# using java mail api to notify the registered user

Tags: jakarta-mail

actually i am try to notify the user who is registered on my application by sending him  an email message and using following code but continuously it gives the exception java.lang.ClassFormatError how can i get rid of this exception. here is the exception and code

Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in      
 method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException

     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

 Could not find the main class: SendMailTLS.  Program will exit.
```

Code is:

```
 import java.util.Properties;

 import javax.mail.Message;
 import javax.mail.MessagingException;
 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
 import javax.mail.Session;
 import javax.mail.Transport;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


 public class SendMailTLS {


     public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "username@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have javaee.jar or j2ee.jar in your CLASSPATH?  If so, get rid of it.